# Filter jQuery object by class AND no tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

using the following code:

```
// Get the highlighted content
let $content = $(editor.selection.getContent());
```

I get the content that is currently highlighted in TinyMCE.  When I print out the value of `$content` in the Console window I get the following:

```
$content
jQuery.fn.init(5)
    0: span.element.text-element
    1: text
    2: span.element.text-element
    3: text
    4: span.element.text-element
    length: 5
```

what I'm trying to do is verify if all the objects are either of type `.text-element` or text.  So I am performing the following `$content.filter('.text-element').length` and compare it to `$content.length`.  If they are equal my object is good.  But of course just filtering on `'.text-element'` only gives me 3 elements.

I have also tried `$content.filter('.text-element,:not([class]').length` which doesn't work.

How do I return all `'.text-element'`s & elements without a class?

I'll add a TinyMCE tag.

Comment: I'm interested what selector you're using to return a text node within a jQuery object?

Comment: I'm working with TinyMCE and when I perform a `$(editor.selection.getContent())` that's what I get back.  `editor` is a reference to the TinyMCE editor.

Comment: I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by passing a function to `filter()`. The function can check for the presence of the element, or check the nodeType of the element:

```
let $filtered = $foo.filter((i, el) => el.classList.contains('text-element') || el.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE);
```

Comment: I'm getting `classList` and `nodeType` errors of `is not a function at HTMLSpanElement.eval`

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include a working example.

Comment: This answer got me on the right track.  Thanks.